# How to pass a date without TimeZone

Tags: flash, web-services, actionscript-2, webservice-client

I need to pass my Date information to a webservice in the following Format:

> (yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm) 2008-03-12T00:00

But Flash returns me the date object as below format:

> Sat Jan 14 11:32:03 GMT+0530 2012

Is there anyway I can modify the date object to hold the datetime as in the format below ,i.e:

> (yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm) 2008-03-12T00:00

Answer (score 0):

1. Date is a number of milliseconds since the beginning of UNIX epoch. It is not a sting, so if you need to pass it to a web service, send that number, sending a string is many times less efficient.
2. If you need to format date to display it to user, there is a `DateTimeFormatter` class (not sure since when, so check your version requirements before using it). I don't understand what 'T' was supposed to convey in your example, so I deliberately omitted it, other than that, the code would look like the following:

   ```
   var date:Date = new Date();
   var formatter:DateTimeFormatter = new DateTimeFormatter("en_US");
   formatter.setDateTimePattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
   trace(formatter.format(date));
   ```

Comment: I am sending date as date object itself to web service.Shall I pass it as a Number and How?

Comment: sending dates as a string is how you use web services. The following XML schema specification describes how dateTime strings are formatted: http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#dateTime.